# Why is command created with expl3 does not work with command as an argument?

Tags: pdftex, expl3, latex3

I'm trying to create my regex command, with `expl3`, that will push dash behind words shorter than three characters. That no problem and its work with simple text, but when I try `\input` or `\include` as an argument, my regex doesn't work. After that, I create new command with text included in the file, but that doesn't work too.

As an example, I'm writing code below, it's same as the core of my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myCommand_tl
\cs_new:Npn \myCommand #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_myCommand_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {([\ \t\n\_\/]{1})(.{1,3})([\ \t\n]{1})} {\1\2\-} \l_myCommand_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_myCommand_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\SomeText}{Just put dast behind words with three or less length.}

\begin{document}

\myCommand{Just put dast behind words with three or less length.}

\myCommand{\SomeText}

\end{document}
```

And here is `pdflatex` output.

[image: Latex output.]

Is there anything that I can do? I tried to use `\expandafter`, but this doesn't work for me. Must I use `\NewDocumentCommand`? If it's true, how can I do it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood how to use the new LaTeX3 naming convention, as well as the separation between programming layer and document layer. Here's how you could do it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l_jiri_tmpa_tl
  \cs_new:Npn \jiri_dash_putter:n #1 {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_jiri_tmpa_tl { #1 }
      \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b(\w{1,3})\b } { \1\2- } \l_jiri_tmpa_tl
      \tl_use:N \l_jiri_tmpa_tl
  }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \jiri_dash_putter:n { e }
  \NewDocumentCommand \myCommand { m }
    { \jiri_dash_putter:e { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\SomeText}{Just put dash behind words with three or less length.}

\begin{document}

\myCommand{Just put dash behind words with three or less length.}

\myCommand{\SomeText}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

That is:

- Group all the names you define into a module, I called it `jiri` here.
- Adhere to the naming convention in the programming layer. Particularly, any function defined with `\cs_new:Npn` must adhere to this convention. Have a look at the [LaTeX3](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) documentation for details.
- Use [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) for defining document-level functions.
- In order to expand macros before applying the regex, make use of the LaTeX3 expansion control capabilities. (I used the `e` variant here.)

As a side node, you could just use the scratch variable `\l_tmpa_tl` here, instead of defining your own.